# saving to django model gives null error even though model field has default value

Tags: django, django-models

When saving to a django model via a dict which does have the key and value  `{...,'type': None,...}`

the model field is
`type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=Type.CHOICES, default=Type.EITHER)`

However when trying to save I get an error: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "type" violates not-null constraint`

Does the ORM in django not try to use the default value if a `None` is specified directly? How best should this be handled?

Update, more details on saving.

There is no custom save method in the model.

In the view this is being saved via

views.py

```py
...
                account = Account()
                account_data = {}
                ...
                preferences = ['type', 'payment_method_preference', ...]
                account_fields = preferences + other_fields
                for key in account_fields:
                    account_data[key] = request.session['supply_address'].get(key)
                keys_to_attr(account_data, account)
                account.address = address
                account.payment = direct_debit
                account.save()
```

Comment: You need to show the code you're using to create and save the model.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is quite strange.

Your problem happens because you explicitly set every attribute, even if it is None, therefore overriding the default which was assigned on instantiation. You could check for this:

```
for key in account_fields:
    value = request.session['supply_address'].get(key)
    if value is not None:
        account_data[key] = value
```

but really I would re-think what you are doing, I'm not sure why you want to copy a bunch of fields around instead of, for example, having Address as a separate model with a foreign key from Account.

Comment: Thanks I didn't reaslise the default value was assigned on instantiation, (thought it would be on save).  Thanks for confirming.  Each view is saved to the session and `supply_address` is a poor name for data from a particular view which contains address data for the `Address` model but also other data to be saved into the account model.  (the forms in the views have been decoupled from the models in order to get the data from the user in a specific order)